# Youtube-dl download script debug

Tags: bash, macos, youtube, youtube-dl

Dumping very bad idea of updating this post. New place for this script:
https://gist.github.com/Wogol/66e9936b6d49cc5fecca59eaeca1ca2e

---

Im trying to create a .command macOS script (Should also work under GNU/Linux) that use Youtube-dl that is simple to use. I have fixed so it downloads description, thumbnail, subtitles, json, creates folder structure and also saves video ID, uploader and upload date.

---

**ISSUES WITH THE MAIN SCRIPT:**

- **FIXED (13th august)** Problem I struggle with is the option of Audio & Video or Audio only. For some reason only audio works in the script. The download script for the video&audio dont work but if I paste that same command line ("The DEBUG output line") in a terminal window it works. Scratching my head.
  Youtube-dl gives me this message:
  ERROR: requested format not available
- **FIXED (31th august)** Get max resolution of video working. Have found information to force mp4 or max resolution but not combined them.

---

**ISSUES WITH INFORMATION FILE:**

Also creating a info file with title, channel name, release date, description. Im now struggling with getting video information from .json and youtube-dl to be exported into the info.txt file.

- **FIXED (5th september)** textfile=""$folder"info.txt" not working. Gives this error: (There I want to add youtube-dl folder.

```
    ytdl.command: line 104: ~/Downloads/ytdl/dog_vids/info.txt: No such file or directory
```

- **FIXED (5th september)** Find youtube-dl folder and get it to work with grep.
  Something like this:

```
   youtube-dl --simulate --SHOW_THE_OUTPUT_PATH -o $folder'/%(title)s/%(title)s - (%(id)s) - %(uploader)s - %(upload_date)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

- **FIXED (5th september)** With grep command i named the json file "*.json" because there will only be one per directory but I dont like that solution. (Could be answered with point above)
- **FIXED (5th september)** How to make so grep dont grab "? It now adds them before and after everything.
- **FIXED (5th september)** How to get the tags information from json file? Tags look like this:

```
    "tags": ["music", "video", "classic"]
```

- **FIXED (5th september)** Run the creation of info file part of the script in the background of downloading the video?

---

***CURRENT VERSION TRYING TO GET IT WORKING***

(12 august)

```
    textfile=""$folder"info.txt"
    
    echo TITLE >> ~/Downloads/ytdl/dog_vids/info.txt
    youtube-dl -e $url >> ~/Downloads/ytdl/dog_vids/info.txt
    echo \ >> ~/Downloads/ytdl/dog_vids/info.txt
    
    echo CHANNEL >> $textfile
    echo \ >> $textfile
    
    echo CHANNEL URL >> $textfile
    echo \ >> $textfile
    
    echo UPLOAD DATE >> $textfile
    echo \ >> $textfile
    
    echo URL >> $textfile
    echo $url >> $textfile
    echo \ >> $textfile
    
    echo TAGS >> $textfile
    echo \ >> $textfile
    
    echo DESCRIPTION >> $textfile
    youtube-dl --get-description $url >> $textfile
```

---

***EXPERIMENT FUTURE VERSION - EXTRACTING INFORMATION FROM JSON FILE***

This isnt a working script. Showing how I want it with $textfile, $ytdlfolder and $jsonfile.

```
    url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    
    textfile=""$folder""$YOUTUBE-DL_PATH"info.txt"
    ytdlfolder="$folder""$YOUTUBE-DL_PATH"
    jsonfile="$folder""$YOUTUBE-DL_JSON-FILE"

    Echo TITLE >> $textfile
    grep -o '"title": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $textfile
    Echo \ >> $textfile
    
    Echo CHANNEL >> $textfile
    grep -o '"uploader": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $textfile
    Echo \ >> $textfile
    
    Echo CHANNEL URL >> $textfile
    grep -o '"uploader_url": *"[^"]*"' *.json | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $textfile
    Echo \ >> $textfile
    
    Echo UPLOAD DATE >> $textfile
    grep -o '"upload_date": *"[^"]*"' *.json | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $textfile
    Echo \ >> $textfile
    
    Echo TAGS >> $textfile
    grep -o '"tags": *"[^"]*"' *.json | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $textfile
    Echo \ >> $textfile
    
    echo URL >> $textfile
    echo $url >> $textfile
    echo \ >> $textfile
    
    Echo DESCRIPTION >> $textfile
    youtube-dl --get-description $url >> $textfile
```

---

***THE SCRIPT:***

12 august.

- Moved url to the top so when user paste the url they get the videos title back. This so the user know they got the right video.
- Added max resolution 1920x1080. (Do not work)

13 august.

- Downloading Audio & Video works.

31 august.

- Fixed force mp4 and max heigh of 1080.

5 september.

- Finally working script. Read more about it here (Or scroll down):
  [Youtube-dl download script debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336809/youtube-dl-download-script-debug/63753752#63753752)

2020-09-17

- Folders can now have spaces in them.

**2020-09-22**

- Select menus is now one column.
- Minor fixes.
- Now all the bugs is fixed. Issues left is only optimizations.

```
    #! /bin/bash
    ################################################################################
    # Script Name: Youtube-dl Easy Download Script
    # Description: Easy to use script to download YouTube videos with a couple of
    #              options.
    #
    # What this script do:
    #   - Downloads video in MP4 with highest quality and max resolution 1920x1080.
    #   - Downloads thumbnail and subtitles.
    #   - Gives user option where to download the video and video or only audio.
    #   - Creates a folder with same name as video title and puts all files there.
    #   - Creates a .txt file with information about the video.
    #
    #
    # Author:      Wogol - Stackoverflow.com, Github.com
    # License:     The GNU General Public License v3.0 - GNU GPL-3
    #
    # 
    # Big thanks to the people at youtube-dl GitHub and Stack Overflow. Without
    # their help this would never ever been possible for me.
    #
    # Special thanks to:
    #              Reino @ Stack Overflow
    #
    # #####
    #
    # Software required:                 youtube-dl, xidel, printf
    #
    # macOS:       1. Install Homebrew:  https://brew.sh
    #              2. Terminal command:  brew install youtube-dl xidel
    #
    # Linux:       Depends on package manager your distribution use.
    #
    # #####
    #
    # Version history:
    # 2020-09-22
    #   - Select menus is now one column.
    #   - Minor fixes.
    #   - Now all the bugs is fixed. Issues left is only optimizations.
    #
    # 2020-09-17
    #   - Folders can now have spaces in them.
    #
    # 2020-09-05
    #   - First working version.
    #
    # #####
    #
    # Issues left:
    #   - In the beginning there is a confirmation that show the title of the
    #     video so user know they got the correct video. It takes youtube-dl a
    #     couple of seconds. To speed up the script it is DISABLED by default.
    #
    #   - Have found out that the script dont need xidel to get json information
    #     but youtube-dl can get it. Dont know how to use youtube-dl --dump-json
    #     to get the same result.
    #
    #   - To get the path to the .txt file script use youtube-dl. This gives the
    #     script a pause for a few seconds. Best would get to get the path some how
    #     without connecting to YouTube again but use the output from youtube-dl
    #     some how. ... or run it in the background when video is downloading.
    #
    ################################################################################



    clear


    
    # - WELCOME MESSAGE -

    echo

    COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
    title="-= Youtube-dl Easy Download Script =-" 
    printf "%*s\n" $(((${#title}+$COLUMNS)/2)) "$title"



    # - PASTE URL -

    echo -e "\n*** - Paste URL address and hit RETURN. Example:\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ --OR-- https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ\n"

    read url



    # - VIDEO TITLE -

    # So users know they have the correct URL.

    #echo -e "\nThe video is: (This takes 3-4 seconds, or more ...)"
    #youtube-dl -e $url
    #echo



    # - DOWNLOAD LOCATION -

    
    # DIRECTORY MUST END WITH SLASH: /


    echo -e "\n\n*** - Choose download folder:\n"
    
    COLUMNS=0
    PS3='Choose: '
    select directory in "~/Downloads/ytdl/Rick Astley/" "~/Downloads/ytdl/Never Gonna Give You Up/" "~/Downloads/ytdl/Other Rick Videos/" ; do
    echo -e "\nOption $REPLY selected. Download directory is:\n $directory"



    # - AUDIO/VIDEO SETTINGS -

    echo -e "\n\n*** - Choose download settings:\n"

    COLUMNS=0
    PS3='Choose: '
    options=("Audio & Video" "Audio only")
    select settingsopt in "${options[@]}"
        do
    case $settingsopt in

    "Audio & Video")
    av="-f bestvideo[ext=mp4][height<=1080]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best --merge-output-format mp4"

    ;;

    "Audio only")
    av="-f bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestaudio"

    ;;

    esac

    echo -e "\nOption $REPLY selected:\n $settingsopt"



    # - THE DOWNLOAD SCRIPT -

    echo -e "\n\n*** - Starting download:\n"
    youtube-dl $av --write-thumbnail --all-subs --restrict-filenames -o "$directory%(title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s" $url



    # - INFORMATION FILE -

    textfile=$(youtube-dl --get-filename --restrict-filenames -o "$directory%(title)s/%(title)s.txt" $url)

    xidel -s "$url" -e '
    let $json:=json(
        //script/extract(.,"ytplayer.config = (.+?\});",1)[.]
      )/args,
      $a:=json($json/player_response)/videoDetails,
      $b:=json($json/player_response)/microformat
    return (
    "- TITLE -",
    $a/title,"",
    "- CHANNEL -",
    $a/author,"",
    "- CHANNEL URL -",
    $b//ownerProfileUrl,"",
    "- UPLOAD DATE -",
    $b//publishDate,"",
    "- URL -",
    $json/loaderUrl,"",
    "- TAGS -",
    $a/keywords,"",
    "- DESCRIPTION -",
    $a/shortDescription
    )
    ' --printed-json-format=compact >> "$textfile"



    # - THE END -
    
    echo
    COLUMNS=$(tput cols) 
    ending="Download Complete!"
    printf "%*s\n\n" $(((${#ending}+$COLUMNS)/2)) "$ending"
    
    exit
    
    done
    done
```

Comment: Have updated the main post a couple of times over the days because of progress.

Issues with the main script:
1. Tested download this 4k video but it downloaded it in webm with the height limit. Tested to lower it to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ
(Lot of information about mp4 or max resolution but cant find anything about combining them)
2. The audio&video download do not work. Have no idea why. I run the debug line manually the script creates and that works just fine. When I empty the av="" or replace it with the audio only "Audio&Video" works so the menu script is working.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the script working.

Have got a lot of help from many people but big thanks to Reino with his help in this thread:
[Grep command questions - Grep text from program output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731320/grep-command-questions-grep-text-from-program-output/63752231#63752231)

The script has issues and it can be optimized but I dont know how to fix them. This is the first bash script I have created.

The goals with this was to create a script that:

- Simple and easy to use.
- No terminal commands.
- Initial sorting in different directories.
- Video or only audio.
- MP4 with max resolution 1920x1080 because everything supports it out of the box.
- Text file with additional information about the video.

These are features I miss in programs like Downie (macOS) and Clipgrab.

For other people to use this script and future fixing I tried to create a Github page... not my cup of tea so to say.

---

Script is in the first post on this page.

[Youtube-dl download script debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336809/youtube-dl-download-script-debug)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed so Audio & Video download now works. The problem was ' in the av line. Removed them and now it works fine. Also updated the av line from the man/manual for youtube-dl.

Not working:

```
    av="-f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio' --merge-output-format mp4"
```

Working:

```
    av="-f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best --merge-output-format mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have now fixed so the script force mp4 and max height of 1080.

```
    -f bestvideo[ext=mp4][height<=1080]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best --merge-output-format mp4
```

Now the rest of the issues left.