# Grep command questions - Grep text from program output?

Tags: json, bash, youtube, grep, youtube-dl

I'm trying to extract information from the json file youtube-dl and grep some information from it to a .txt file.

Example the output from youtube-dl when downloading a video.

```
[info] Writing video description to: /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).description
[info] Writing video description metadata as JSON to: /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).info.json
```

**My thinking**

1. Grep .json and .description file paths to use that in future grep commands.
2. Run working version of the script below and it adds the new text above description text in .description file.
3. (Rename .description to .txt)

I prefer this method because youtube-dl is only needed to run one time.

If there are other univeral commands that work on mac and Linux as grep that can make it simple then I see no problem to use them instead of grep.

---

**QUESTIONS**

- How to grep the file paths and use it in other commands described below in the script examples?
- How to run the script below but adding all that information above the current description text in that text file?
- When it get information from the json file it also gets " before and after. So a video name becomes: `"VIDEO NAME"`, but want it `VIDEO NAME` only.
- How to grep the TAGS from the json file? Tags look like this in .json file: `"tags": ["music", "video", "classic"]`. Want to get `"music", "video", "classic"`.

---

**Script example**

```
    txtfile="$GREP_DESCRIPTION_FROM_YOUTUBE-DL_OUTPUT"
    jsonfile="$GREP_JSON_FROM_YOUTUBE-DL_OUTPUT"

    echo TITLE >> $txtfile
    grep -o '"title": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo CHANNEL >> $txtfile
    grep -o '"uploader": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo CHANNEL URL >> $txtfile
    grep -o '"uploader_url": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo UPLOAD DATE >> $txtfile
    grep -o '"upload_date": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo TAGS >> $txtfile
    grep -o '"tags": *"[^"]*"' $jsonfile | grep -o '"[^"]*"$' >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo URL >> $txtfile
    echo $url >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo DESCRIPTION >> $txtfile
```

Comment: Don't use `grep` to process JSON. Use `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Barmer! This answered three of my four questions.

What is left and I cant figure out is how to get json file location from youtube-dl output, get it to work in the script and how to create a .txt file in the same directory but ending with .txt.

Something like this:

1. Grep everything after `[info] Writing video description metadata as JSON to:`  and that is `/Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).info.json`
2. Make that `$jsonfile`
3. Take same output from point 1, replace the extension (everything after the last . DOT), with .txt, make that `$txtfile`

---

Updated script with jq

```
#! /bin/bash

    txtfile="textfile.txt"
    jsonfile="jsonfile.json"

    echo - TITLE - >> $txtfile
    jq -r '.title' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile | echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo - CHANNEL - >> $txtfile
    jq -r '.uploader' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile | echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo - CHANNEL URL - >> $txtfile
    jq -r '.uploader_url' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile | echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo - UPLOAD DATE - >> $txtfile
    jq -r '.upload_date' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile | echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo - URL - >> $txtfile
    jq -r '.webpage_url' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile | echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo - TAGS - >> $txtfile
    jq -r -c '.tags' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
    echo \ >> $txtfile | echo \ >> $txtfile
    
    echo - DESCRIPTION - >> $txtfile
    jq -r '.description' $jsonfile >> $txtfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ youtube-dl --help | grep "dump-json"
    -j, --dump-json                  Simulate, quiet but print JSON information.
```

With this option there's no need to download a video at all. Simply pipe the output of `youtube-dl` to a proper JSON parser. I would recommend [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

```
$ youtube-dl -j https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ | xidel -se '
  $json/(
    "- TITLE -",title,"",
    "- CHANNEL -",uploader,"",
    "- CHANNEL URL -",uploader_url,"",
    "- UPLOAD DATE -",upload_date,"",
    "- URL -",webpage_url,"",
    "- TAGS -",translate(serialize(tags,{"method":"json"}),"[]",""),"",
    "- DESCRIPTION -",description
  )
'
```

*(alternative to format the tags: `join((tags)() ! x"&quot;{.}&quot;",",")`)*

If you already downloaded the video and JSON (with `--write-info-json` I presume), then you can retrieve the filename with `--get-filename`:

```
$ youtube-dl --get-filename https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp4

$ jsonfile=$(youtube-dl --get-filename https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

$ xidel -s "${jsonfile/.mp4/.info}.json" -e '
  $json/(
    [...]
  )
' > "${jsonfile/.mp4/.info}.txt"
```

Output of command, or content of '*Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)-dQw4w9WgXcQ.info.txt*':

```
- TITLE -
Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)

- CHANNEL -
RickAstleyVEVO

- CHANNEL URL -
http://www.youtube.com/user/RickAstleyVEVO

- UPLOAD DATE -
20091024

- URL -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

- TAGS -
"the boys soundtrack","the boys amazon prime","Never gonna give you up the boys","RickAstleyvevo","vevo","official","Rick Roll","video","music video","Rick Astley album","rick astley official","single","album","together forever","Never Gonna Give You Up","Whenever You Need Somebody","pop","rickrolled","WRECK-IT RALPH 2","Fortnite song Fortnite item shop Fortnite time shop today Fortnite montage","Fortnite event","Fortnite dance","fortnite never gonna give you up"

- DESCRIPTION -
Rick Astley's official music video for "Never Gonna Give You Up" Listen to Rick Astley: https://RickAstley.lnk.to/_listenYD Subscribe to the official Rick As...
```

Actually there's no need for `youtube-dl` if this information is all you're after. Parsing the html-source would suffice:

```
$ xidel -s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ -e '
  "- TITLE -",//meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content,"",
  "- CHANNEL -",//meta[@itemprop="channelId"]/@content,"",
  "- CHANNEL URL -",//span[@itemprop="author"]/link/@href,"",
  "- UPLOAD DATE -",//meta[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content,"",
  "- URL -",//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content,"",
  "- TAGS -",join(//meta[@property="og:video:tag"]/x"&quot;{@content}&quot;",","),"",
  "- DESCRIPTION -",//meta[@itemprop="description"]/@content
'
```

The html-source also has a huge JSON with all the information you need. It's a bit more difficult to extract, but can be done:

```
$ xidel -s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ -e '
  parse-json(//script/extract(.,"ytInitialPlayerResponse = (\{.+\})",1))/(
    "- TITLE -",videoDetails/title,"",
    "- CHANNEL -",videoDetails/channelId,"",
    "- CHANNEL URL -",microformat//ownerProfileUrl,"",
    "- UPLOAD DATE -",microformat//publishDate,"",
    "- URL -","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="||videoDetails/videoId,"",
    "- TAGS -",translate(serialize(videoDetails/keywords,{"method":"json"}),"[]",""),"",
    "- DESCRIPTION -",x:lines(videoDetails/shortDescription)[1]
  )
'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that input.
...But this is part of a script Im trying to create. Its to create a text file with information about the downloaded video. The file should be in the same folder as the video and have the same name as the video but with ending .txt instead.

Also want to connect to Youtube as few times as possible, use defailt software on mac+linux and also make the script simple.

If it is possible with your first examples output to the txt file would be the best. No json file needed to be downloaded.

Comment: Path to files that youtube-dl show when downloading is this. So some how get one of them, video file prefered, and then change mp4 to txt and save the output from xidel there.

[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Writing thumbnail to: /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).webp
[download] Destination: /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp4

Comment: @Wogol See the edited answer on how to retrieve the filename.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed problem talked about below.**

Solved it by adding two " at the end of the script at the end

```
...
' --printed-json-format=compact >> "$textfile"
```

Thanks Reino!

---

Thanks. Have now tried to get it working. It gave me some errors and started with some troubleshooting. Still no luck.

This test to see if it works. `folder` and `url` comes earlier in the script and is here temporary.

```
    folder=/Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/ytdl/
    url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    textfile=$(youtube-dl --get-filename -o $folder'%(title)s/%(title)s.txt' $url)
    $textfile
```

Output is:

```
-bash: /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/ytdl/Rick: No such file or directory
```

And if I create that folder the output is

```
-bash: /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/ytdl/Rick: is a directory
```

But if I test the script exactly how I think it should look like

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o /Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/ytdl/'%(title)s/%(title)s.txt' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

The output is:

```
/Users/ACCOUNT/Downloads/ytdl/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)/Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).txt
```

Exactly how it should look like. What am I doing wrong?

---

This is the xidel script and how I changed it, `$url` and `>> $textfile`. I use this script because it gets the complete description.

```
xidel -s "$url" -e '
  let $json:=json(
        //script/extract(.,"ytplayer.config = (.+?\});",1)[.]
      )/args,
      $a:=json($json/player_response)/videoDetails,
      $b:=json($json/player_response)/microformat
  return (
    "- TITLE -",
    $a/title,"",
    "- CHANNEL -",
    $a/author,"",
    "- CHANNEL URL -",
    $b//ownerProfileUrl,"",
    "- UPLOAD DATE -",
    $b//publishDate,"",
    "- URL -",
    $json/loaderUrl,"",
    "- TAGS -",
    $a/keywords,"",
    "- DESCRIPTION -",
    $a/shortDescription
  )
' --printed-json-format=compact >> $textfile
```

Comment: Use curly brackets for the variable and quote it: `-o '${folder}%(title)s/%(title)s.txt'`.

Comment: This website is not like a forum. If you have another question, then you have to start a new one. Answering a question shouldn't contain another question.